# Linestyle in matplotlib step function

Tags: python, matplotlib, linestyle

Is it possible to set the linestyle in a matplotlib step function to dashed, dotted, etc.?

I've tried:

```
step(x, linestyle='--'), 
step(x, '--')
```

But it did not help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As of mpl 1.3.0 this is fixed upstream

---

You have to come at it a bit sideways as `step` seems to ignore `linestyle`.  If you look at what `step` is doing underneath, it is just a thin wrapper for plot.

You can do what you want by talking to `plot` directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(5), range(5), linestyle='--', drawstyle='steps')
plt.plot(range(5), range(5)[::-1], linestyle=':', drawstyle='steps')
plt.xlim([-1, 5])
plt.ylim([-1, 5])
```

[image: example]

`['steps', 'steps-pre', 'steps-mid', 'steps-post']` are the valid values for `drawstyle` and  control where the step is drawn.

[Pull](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1802) request resulting from this question, I personally think this is a bug. [edit: this has been pulled into master and should show up in v1.3.0].

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this effect while still using plt.hist(...)?