# How to change linestyle in matplotlib Step function?

Tags: matplotlib

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y1 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.step(x1, y1, alpha=0.8, linewidth=2, color="b", linestyle="--", label="test")
```

[image]

Why the linestyle parameter doesn't effect this plot? And how to make it work?
The documentation mentions "Additional keyword args to step() are the same as those for plot()." [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=step#matplotlib.axes.Axes.step)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of matplotlib are you using?

This is a bug/interface issue ([PR #1802](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1802)) that was fixed in 1.3.0.

If you can not upgrade, see the work-around at 
[Linestyle in matplotlib step function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188005/linestyle-in-matplotlib-step-function/15191183#15191183).

Answer (score 1):

Add 'dashes=(a,b)' to ax.plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y1 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax.step(x1, y1, alpha=0.8, linewidth=2, color="b", linestyle="--", dashes=(4,2), label="test")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You just pasted the OPs code back with and added import and show which are clearly not the problem.

Comment: The difference is not the import and show but dashes. It works fine with me on python 2.7 with matplotlib 1.1.1. The original code just gives a solid line. Please read next time...

Comment: You should edit your answer to include an explanation of _what_ is different and why it should work.  Please make your answers clear next time.