# Matplotlib: ValueError: 'steps' is not a valid value for ls

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code came from the [Matplotlib 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/en-au/product/matplotlib-30-cookbook-9781789135718?type=print&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAlcyuBhBnEiwAOGZ2S5AG1tIdmdDusS18Q4CYS6Cv8c3TLClPdVPEMOz85nEEyw5kpOYxmRoCJLoQAvD_BwE)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(321)
ax2 = plt.subplot(322)
ax3 = plt.subplot(323)
ax4 = plt.subplot(324)
ax5 = plt.subplot(325)
ax6 = plt.subplot(326)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)

color_list = ['xkcd:sky blue', 'green', '#1F1F1F1F', 'b', '#1C0B2D', 'tab:pink', 'C4']
for i, color in enumerate(color_list):
    y = x - (-5*i + 15)
    ax1.plot(x, y, color)
ax1.set_title('colors demo')

line_style = ['-', '--', '-.', ':', '.']
for i, ls in enumerate(line_style):
    y = x - (-5*i + 15)
    line, = ax2.plot(x, y, ls)
ax2.set_title('line style demo')
plt.setp(line, ls='steps') # PROBLEMATIC CODE

marker_list = ['.', ',', 'o', 'v', '^', 's', 'p', '*', 'h', 'H', 'D']
for i, marker in enumerate(marker_list):
    y = x - (-5*i + 15)
    ax3.plot(x, y, marker)
ax3.set_title('marker demo')

y = x          # reset y to x
ax4.plot(x, y-10, 'k-d')
ax4.plot(x, y-5, 'c--')
ax4.plot(x, y, '|')
ax4.plot(x, y+5, '-.')
ax4.plot(x, y+10, color='purple', ls=':', marker='3')
ax4.plot(x, y+15, color='orange', linestyle=':', marker='1')
ax4.set_title('combination demo')

ax5.plot(x, y-10, 'y-D', linewidth=2, markersize=4, markerfacecolor='red',  
         markeredgecolor='k',markeredgewidth=1)
ax5.plot(x, y-5, 'm-s', lw=4, ms=6, markerfacecolor='red', 
         markeredgecolor='y', markeredgewidth=1)
ax5.set_title('Line and Marker Sizes Demo')

dash_capstyles = ['butt','projecting','round']
for i, cs in enumerate(dash_capstyles):
    y = x - (-5*i + 15)
    ax6.plot(x, y, ls='--', lw=10, dash_capstyle=cs)
ax6.set_title('dash capstyle demo')

plt.tight_layout();
plt.show()
```

Although the book showed the output as per below
[image]

I couldn't replicate the result, but got the following error (for the line `plt.setp(line, ls='steps'`) instead:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[114], line 25
     23     line, = ax2.plot(x, y, ls)
     24 ax2.set_title('line style demo')
---> 25 plt.setp(line, ls='steps')
ValueError: 'steps' is not a valid value for ls; supported values are '-', '--', '-.', ':', 'None', ' ', '', 'solid', 'dashed', 'dashdot', 'dotted'
```

Could someone please help me how to fix the error and draw the step line (highlighted in yellow in the image above)?

Comment: I can't see anything in the documentation to suggest that a setting like this should be supported. No idea how the book code came up with it. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188005 help?

Comment: Did you mean `plt.setp(line, ds="step")`? `ds` is short for `drawstyle` (ctrl+F for "drawstyle" [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html)).

Comment: The book's code is quite sloppy.  `plt.setp(line, ds="steps")` should work. The older versions of matplotlib probably just ignored the illegal `ls='steps'` instead of showing an error. And the author didn't wonder why no steps were seen in the plot.

Comment: Amazing @jared and @JohancC. How did you know to look for the `ds` argument in the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` when the book's code didn't indicate anything? Thanks

Comment: Just look for "steps" in [the Line2D docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html)

Comment: Sorry for my poorly phrased question, @JohanC. What I meant was how did you know to go to `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` at the first place because the book code only mentioned about `plt.figure, plt.subplot, plt.setp...`, nothing about `Line2D`. I'd love to know the thought process so that I can apply it to other situations. Thanks

Comment: Well, the error message points to the `line` object returned by `ax.plot()` and complaints about its valid attributes. `ax.plot()` returns a tuple of `Line2D` objects. The official documentation is the best place to know the valid attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The error `ValueError: 'steps' is not a valid value for ls` occurs because `ls` (linestyle) in `plt.setp(line, ls='steps')` is intended for line styles like solid, dashed, etc., not for step-like lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ... (rest of the code remains the same)

line_style = ['-', '--', '-.', ':', '.']
for i, ls in enumerate(line_style):
    y = x - (-5*i + 15)
    line, = ax2.plot(x, y, ls)
ax2.set_title('line style demo')

# Correct the problematic line:
plt.setp(line, drawstyle='steps-pre')  # Use drawstyle for step-like lines

# ... (rest of the code remains the same)
```